# Adb shows 'device' in command line but unauthorized in Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, adb, device

I am using USB debugging with my Cubot S208 for my Android App.

If I type `adb devices` into command line I receive the following:

`0123456789ABCDEF        device`

So clearly the device is authorized.

However, in Android Studio I receive the following message:

`for device 0123456789ABCDEF: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device.`

Why is this the case?

The device is recognized by Android studio under the name "Cubot S208" properly recognizes the debuggable applications too.

So everything seems fine.

I have ALWAYS allowed USB debugging from my Laptop when the message came up on my phone screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: my symphony pd1 phone, running kaios, is showing the same device code and unauthorized in cmd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> for device 0123456789ABCDEF: device unauthorized. Please check the
>   confirmation dialog on your device.

Execute these adb commands:

```
adb kill-server 
adb start-server
```

After that reconnect your device and tick debugging option on device.

Comment: once restart device, after that follow steps, It works fine for me everytime

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the debugging authorizations from your phone, disconnect it and reconnect it. Failing that try killing adb and then try launching